# Is it possible to change an app version name from 2 part style(2.3) to 3 part style(2.3.1)?

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project version name is something like `versionName "2.3"`.
And I need to set it `versionName "2.3.1"` for the next release.
Is it possible?

Does the store support it?

Comment: You can add any string to version name, from "3.0" to "1.1", or from "2.3.1.1" to "newversion" is fine. Version code is the one that matter.

Comment: any string can be used, regardless of everything.

Comment: Thanke you @koceeng

Comment: Thanke you @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explain in the [manifest documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

`android:versionName : String`

> The version number shown to users. This attribute can be set as a raw string or as a reference to a string resource. The string has no other purpose than to be displayed to users. The versionCode attribute holds the significant version number used internally.

`android:versionCode`

> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName attribute. 
>   The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define it however you want, as long as each successive version has a higher number. For example, it could be a build number. Or you could translate a version number in "x.y" format to an integer by encoding the "x" and "y" separately in the lower and upper 16 bits. Or you could simply increase the number by one each time a new version is released.

So yes you can, `versionName` is only here to show a readable name for the version to the user. This could be "My app #1" if you want

This is the `versionCode` that should grow (not necessary by one) on each new version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is no problem. The version name is only a human-visible String that can be anything.